# What is the application of CGI, does it still in use?

Tags: cgi

I am working on a web app project and when I run testing for security issues, I see CGI directory not found message and want to know more about CGI. Following, I tried to check how it works. I am looking to have application specific use case, particularly related to Go programing language.

I tried to see blogs, but didn't get clear info.

Answer (score -1):

As I run vulnerability tests on my Go web app, I keep encountering this curious message: "CGI directory not found." It's quite surprising since everything's built with modern tools and languages.

During my exploration, I learned that:

- CGI still lingers in older applications and niche scenarios. It played a crucial role in generating dynamic content in the early days.
- CGI scripts can offer unique solutions when existing frameworks lack specific functionalities.
- However, modern practices favor alternatives like server-side scripting languages. They offer efficiency and scalability for dynamic content generation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).